# RabbitMQ Wcf Binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, rabbitmq

what is the point on having RabbitMQ with WCF Binding instead of plain WCF?
Is there any advantage when using RabbitMQ except for using it?
regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It serves the same purpose as the [netMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx) but without requiring Microsoft's Messaging technology (MSMQ) to be installed and configured on the client and the server.

Comment: what are the benefits of using rabbitmq wcf instead of lets say net.tcp wcf?

Comment: Messages are guaranteed to be delivered with either MSMQ or Rabbit MQ but not over other WCF bindings. That and not having to install MSMQ are pretty much the only reasons you'd pick Rabbit MQ over other WCF bindings.

Comment: I think WCF has a reliable session somewhere that guaratees delivery.

Comment: Actually, WCF [reliable sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx) **do not** guarantee delivery. Guaranteed delivery means that if the server that hosts your WCF service suddenly crashes for some reason then a message sent through the Rabbit MQ binding (or netMsmqBinding) while it is down will be still delivered when the server comes back up. Reliable sessions simply go away when a server crashes.

Comment: This is because the message is send to the queue and the host picks it up from there. But what happens to the "session" of the client? Can the host after a restart send the reply to the same client? Will the channel not be faulted?

Comment: The Rabbit MQ binding supports reliable session and duplex services which netMsmqBinding does not. The netMsmqBinding only supports one-way messages. I'm not sure if the Rabbit MQ binding sessions are "durable" meaning they can survive a service crash. All the capabilities of the Rabbit MQ binding are [described in this document.](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.6.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.6.0-wcf-service-model.pdf)